# jQuery - How to set css background color

Tags: jquery

How to set css background color for html tag  by url? (after loading the page).

**Example 1:**
The specified address: http://example.com/list/#c

```
<div id="list">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#a">link-aaa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#b">link-bbb</a></li>
      <li><a href="#c">link-ccc</a></li> <!-- need to mark this line --> 
      <li><a href="#d">link-ddd</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Example 2:** The specified address: http://example.com/list/#d

```
<div id="list">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#a">link-aaa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#b">link-bbb</a></li>
      <li><a href="#c">link-ccc</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#d">link-ddd</a></li> <!-- need to mark this line --> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

I do not know how to apply the css style in the jquery for that item 
jQuery.

```
???.style.backgroundColor='red';
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. What do you mean `by url`? Where would the colour "red" in this instance come from? From the href itself, or from the contents of the link?

Comment: Match url (#c) and <a href="#c">. It will always be red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#list li a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"').css({ backgroundColor: 'red' })
```

You can use the attribute selector `[]` with an href `a[href='#yourhash']`. Then just bring in the current hash value from the url (`window.location.hash`) and set a property with javascript.

I would personally use a class rather than specifically setting the CSS. Also make sure to reset the background colour, or remove the class, on all other tags before setting this one.

Comment: `window.location.hash` already returns #hash... no need for `"#" +`

Comment: I did it without the extra hash at first, then thought maybe it needed it. Couldn't remember from the top of my head. Cheers.

Comment: No problem bud :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the hash on load:

`var hash = window.location.hash;`

Then you can apply css to `a` with a `href` equal to `hash`
`$('a[href$="'+hash+'"]').css('color','red');`